# Shift+Tab in Jupyter Notebook does not work properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to look up the signature and docstring by using Shift+Tab but it did not show as demonstrated on the tutorial on Youtube even though i coded in the same way. The first image is what was demonstrated and the second image is what was shown after i pressed Shift+Tab.

[What is shown on the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9RcM.jpg)
[What is shown when i pressed Shift+Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5kMm.png)